# How to insert multiple records in symfony 1.4?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony-1.4, doctrine-1.2

I try to insert 1 000 - 30 000 records in one http request. And I cannot manage with this.

My codes:

```
foreach ($recipients as $recipient) {
    $notificationHubAction = new NotificationHubAction();
    $notificationHubAction->setNotificationId($popup->getId());
    $notificationHubAction->setUserId($recipient['id']);
    $notificationHubAction->save();
    $notificationHubAction->free();
}



$notificationHubActions = new Doctrine_Collection('NotificationHubAction');
foreach ($recipients as $recipient) {
    $notificationHubAction = new NotificationHubAction();
    $notificationHubAction->setNotificationId($popup->getId());
    $notificationHubAction->setUserId($recipient['id']);
    $notificationHubActions->add($notificationHubAction);
}
$notificationHubActions->save();
```

Both don't work :( Trying to save almost 20 000 records.

Comment: Instead of updating your question to include the answer, you should better post an answer an accept it. This is the way Stackoverflow works to define a question as resolved.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use clear SQL, not Doctrine DQL or something like that.
http://oldforum.symfony-project.org/index.php/m/98628/#msg_num_5